# Why doesn't this array search work for me?

Tags: php

I have a simple array search I'm doing with php.

```
$qs = 'something$';

// check if string has bad characters...
$bad_chars = array('$',',',' ','?','=','&','-','|','@','#','%','^','*','(',')','{','}','|','\\','[',']','/','`','~');

if(in_array($qs,$bad_chars)) {
  echo 'bad characters';
}
```

To me, this should echo 'bad characters', but it doesn't.

What am I missing?

Comment: if any of the answers helped you solve your problem, you should mark it "accepted" / upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATE:*** [benchmark](https://gist.github.com/879119), comparing the 4 answers with code:

100,000 iterations over the test_bad_charachters function, no output:

[Jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348269/why-doesnt-this-array-search-work-for-me/5348425#5348425) (`for/str/in_array`): 32 sec
[Mike Lewis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348269/why-doesnt-this-array-search-work-for-me/5348274#5348274) (`foreach/str_split/in_array`): 23 sec
[Gaurav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348269/why-doesnt-this-array-search-work-for-me/5348308#5348308) (`array_intersect/!=`): 8 sec
[my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348269/why-doesnt-this-array-search-work-for-me/5348493#5348493) (`str_replace/==`): 4 sec

***UPDATE END***

as the other answers point out, `in_array($qs, $bad_chars)` does not test if *the characters* of `$qs` are in `$bad_chars`, but *the whole string* `$qs` (which obviously it is not). to get the expected result, you have to test the single characters of `$qs`.

here is a solution that should do this *fast*:

```
<?php
$qs = 'something$';

// bad characters
$bad_chars = array('$',',',' ','?','=','&','-','|','@','#','%','^','*','(',')','{','}','|','\\','[',']','/','`','~');

// replace all bad characters in $qs with \00. if the resulting string 
// differs from the original string, it has bad characters.
// using a single call to str_replace should make this faster than all 
// other suggested solutions - see the benchmark in the UPDATE.
if (str_replace($bad_chars, '\0', $qs) == $qs) {
  echo 'bad characters';
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution...what did you use to measure the speed?

Comment: @Jason i made a basic benchmark script: 1) wrap the 4 solutions in functions, f1()-f4(), 2) write an outer for loop, $i = 1-4; 3) inside that loop, $start_time = time(); $f = "f$i"; 4) write an inner for loop, $j = 1-100000; 5) inside that inner loop, call the $i'th function via $f(); 6) after the 100000 iterations, the time used by the current function is time() - $start_time; print it; 7) do the same for the remaining test_bad_character implementations. if you are interested, i can put the code somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = str_split($qs);

if(array_intersect($array, $bad_chars) != array())
{
    echo 'bad characters';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because it is seeing if "something$" is an element in $bad_chars, which it isn't.

**Edit:**

Solution:

```
<?php
$qs = 'something$';

// check if string has bad characters...
$bad_chars = array('$',',',' ','?','=','&','-','|','@','#','%','^','*','(',')','{','}','|','\\','[',']','/','`','~');

foreach(str_split($qs) as $char){

  if(in_array($char, $bad_chars)){

    echo $char. " was bad char";
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: e.g. you need to explode the qs and see if each char it contains matches to any one of the bad_chars

Comment: You can use `str_split($qs)` to split a string into an array of chars.

Answer (score 0):

you are searching for the full `"something$"'`, not just the bad `"$"` - this is why.

look for doc in http://php.net/in_array .

Answer (score 0):

Just look at each letter individually instead of the word as a whole.

```
$qs = 'something$';

$bad_chars = array('$',',',' ','?','=','&','-','|','@','#','%','^','*','(',')','{','}','|','\\','[',']','/','`','~');

for($i=0; $i < strlen($qs); $i++) {
 // check if string has bad characters...
 if(in_array($qs[$i],$bad_chars)) {
  echo 'bad characters';
 }
}
```